# RunTime error 1004 when trying to reference a worksheet in a different workbook and assign it to a variable

Tags: excel, vba, variable-assignment

i'm trying to work with two sheets in two different workbooks.
For some reason this code returns an error

```
Sub look()
Dim Source, Destination As Worksheet
Dim Range1_in_Source As Range
Dim Range1_in_Destination As Range

path = "" :file = "file name"

Set Source = Workbooks(2).Worksheets(1)
Set Destination= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```

this assignment returns an object that is empty for Source when i inspect it using watch
Destination however seems to work well -for now!

```
Set Range1_in_Source= Source.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)) 
Set Range1_in_Destination = Destination.Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown))
```

for some reason the last line gives a runtime 1004 error (method 'Range' of object '_global' failed)
And the cells are referring to the Source sheet not Destination.

what is wrong in my code

Comment: You have declared `Source` as `Variant`. The line should be: `Dim Source As Worksheet, Destination As Worksheet`. `Workbooks(2)` is not a good idea it might as well be the same as 'ThisWorkbook'. `xlDown` is also a bad idea. And `Cells` are not qualified. Try posting the full code from `Sub` to `Sub`. There is an edit button below your post.

Comment: Good point, But even after I declare both as worksheet, I still have the exact same problem.I'm not sure the rest of the code will relate to the problem here but I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assignment Issues

- Use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of every module.
- Avoid using `Worksheets(1)` and especially `Workbooks(2)`. They have their `names`, and even better `code names`.
- `xlDown` is mostly avoided in favor of `xlUp`.
- A common mistake is to forget to qualify `Cells`, `Rows` and `Columns`, and even `ranges`.
- For a better readability, use shorter meaningful names for variables.

Your error occurred because you didn't qualify `Cells` (e.g. `src.Cells`, `dest.Cells`...), so the code tried to 'get' a `range` (`object`, not address) on the `destination sheet` 'using' `cells`(`object`, not address) from the `source sheet` which obviously is not possible.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub look()
    
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = Workbooks(2).Worksheets(1)
    Dim dest As Worksheet: Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim rngSrc As Range
    Set rngSrc = src.Range(src.Cells(2, 1), src.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
    Dim rngDest As Range
    Set rngDest = dest.Range(dest.Cells(5, 1), dest.Cells(5, 1).End(xlDown))

    Dim Path As String: Path = ""
    Dim file As String: file = "file name"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much qualifying cells helped in my case. I have further questions if you have time to reply i'd be grateful. 

I don't really get why not using option explicit is bad, if you have a link explaining that it'd be nice. 

I'm not sure how i can use xlUp if i don't know the last row? or am i missing something here?

Comment: `Option Explicit` forces you to declare all variables which helps against unexpected errors and helps you to faster learn and better understand the language. In your case, `xlUp` can be utilized like this: `Set rngDest = dest.Range(dest.Cells(5, 1), dest.Cells(dest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))`.